# lapply to find max value across rows not working as expected

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I am trying to find the max date across rows of a `data.table` using `lapply`. I have some rows where all values in the row are `NA` and in this case I want to return a specific date. I wrote a function to do this but I am not getting the results that I expected.

```
library(data.table)

my.max = function(x){
  if(all(is.na(x))){
    return(as.Date("9999-12-01")) #we can use this to identify which BPIDs have no end date
  }else{
    return(max(x, na.rm = T))
  }
}

DT = data.table("Date1" = c(as.Date("2015-12-30"),NA, NA), "Date2" = c(as.Date("2013-02-04"), as.Date("2014-01-01"), NA))
DT[ , "Row" := 1:.N]

DT[ , "Max_Date" := lapply(.SD, my.max), by = .(Row), .SDcols = c("Date1", "Date2")]
```

This returns

```
> DT
        Date1      Date2 Row   Max_Date
1: 2015-12-30 2013-02-04   1 2015-12-30
2:       <NA> 2014-01-01   2 9999-12-01
3:       <NA>       <NA>   3 9999-12-01
```

So, it does work if all values are `NA`, but if one of the values is `NA` it also returns `9999-12-01`. I put print functions into `my.max` to find out what was happening and it looks like it passes in one value of x at a time. This explains why the `all(is.na(x))` would be true, but I expected it to pass in a vector of both dates in the row. Otherwise, how would it know what values to take the max of?

How can I change my function so it returns `9999-12-01` only if both of the other dates are `NA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method that will work. It encapsulates multiple statements in `{}` to form a single code block:

```
DT[, "this" := {temp=pmax(Date1, Date2, na.rm=TRUE);
                temp[is.na(temp)] = as.Date("9999-12-01"); temp}]
```

which returns

```
DT
        Date1      Date2       this
1: 2015-12-30 2013-02-04 2015-12-30
2:       <NA> 2014-01-01 2014-01-01
3:       <NA>       <NA> 9999-12-01
```

**data**

```
DT = data.table("Date1" = c(as.Date("2015-12-30"),NA, NA),
                "Date2" = c(as.Date("2013-02-04"), as.Date("2014-01-01"), NA))
```

This way, you don't have to loop through each row which can be quite slow.

---

While I don't recommend by-row processing...

```
DT[ , "Row" := 1:.N]
DT[ , "Max_Date" := my.max(unlist(.SD)), by = .(Row), .SDcols = c("Date1", "Date2")]
```

will produce the same output for this example.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I would prefer to do this with lapply if it's possible though since I might need to add in more filtering to the max date later on. Is there anyway to get that to work that you know of?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
library(data.table)

my.max <- function(x){
    if(all(is.na(x))){
        return("9999-12-01") 
    }else{
        return(max(x, na.rm = T))
    }
}

DT <- data.table("Date1" = c(as.Date("2015-12-30"),NA, NA), "Date2" = c(as.Date("2013-02-04"), as.Date("2014-01-01"), NA))
print(DT)
DT[ , "Max_Date" ] <- apply(DT, 1, my.max)
print(DT)



> DT <- data.table("Date1" = c(as.Date("2015-12-30"),NA, NA), "Date2" = c(as.Date("2013-02-04"), as.Date("2014-01-01"), NA))
> print(DT)
        Date1      Date2
1: 2015-12-30 2013-02-04
2:       <NA> 2014-01-01
3:       <NA>       <NA>
> DT[ , "Max_Date" ] <- apply(DT, 1, my.max)
> print(DT)
        Date1      Date2   Max_Date
1: 2015-12-30 2013-02-04 2015-12-30
2:       <NA> 2014-01-01 2014-01-01
3:       <NA>       <NA> 9999-12-01
```

Comment: btw I forgot to include DT[ , "Row" := 1:.N] but you can add it back in the same place it was in your original post and you will get want you are looking for still

Comment: thanks for the response. I'd prefer not to use apply though since it converts it to a matrix first so is rather slow.